# EM algorithm for mixture models, what happens when you don't know how many mixtures you have?

Tags: expectation-maximization

i am trying to learn something here so i tried to estimate the means of two normal distributions that I created. Here is the code:

```
mysum <- function(x) {
 sum(x[is.finite(x)])
}
```

`x<-rnorm(400,0, 1)
y<-rnorm(400,14,8^2)
dat<-c(x,y)
x <- dat
pi1<-0.5
pi2<-0.5
mu1<--0.01
mu2<-0.01
sigma1<-1
sigma2<-8
loglik<- rep(NA, 1000)
loglik[1]<-0
loglik[2]<-mysum(pi1*(log(pi1)+log(dnorm(dat,mu1,sigma1))))+mysum(pi2*(log(pi2)+log(dnorm(dat,mu2,sigma2))))
k<-2`

```
while(abs(loglik[k]-loglik[k-1]) >= 0.00001) {
  tau1<-pi1*dnorm(dat,mean=mu1,sd=sigma1)/(pi1*dnorm(x,mean=mu1,sd=sigma1)+pi2*dnorm(dat,mean=mu2,sd=sigma2))
  tau2<-pi2*dnorm(dat,mean=mu2,sd=sigma2)/(pi1*dnorm(x,mean=mu1,sd=sigma1)+pi2*dnorm(dat,mean=mu2,sd=sigma2))
  pi1<-sum(tau1)/length(dat)
  pi2<-sum(tau2)/length(dat)
  mu1<-sum(tau1*x)/sum(tau1)
  mu2<-sum(tau2*x)/sum(tau2)
  j1<-log(dnorm(x,mu1,sigma1))
  j2<-log(dnorm(x,mu2,sigma2))
for(i in 1:800) {
if(!is.finite(j1[i])) j1[i]<-0.5
if(!is.finite(j2[i])) j2[i]<-0.5
}
  loglik[k+1]<-sum(tau1*(log(pi1)+ j1))+sum(tau2*(log(pi2)+j2))
  k<-k+1
}
```

This code estimates mu1,mu2,pi1 and pi2 well, but what happens if i didnt know how many normal distributions i have? That would mean that i need to estimate n means and n probabilities. What would be the changes in the code?

Comment: If you do not know the number of mixture components, you need to run one EM for each number $k$ and compare the likelihoods with a BIC criterion to penalise for larger $k$. The EM algorithm remains the same. (Including your code in the question is not necessary since your question is not code related.)

Comment: @Xi'an Thanks for the answer sir.So there is no way for an EM algorithm to estimate the number of mixture components? If as you say there is not, then i guess i should apply BIC criterion to the "last" estimated likelihood (the estimated likelihood where  the algorithm achieved convergence )of each different EM (for k=1,2,3 ...). Am I right?

Comment: Yes indeed there is no estimation of $k$ by EM.